# List of ordereddict - get index from values

Tags: python

I have a `List` of `OrderedDict` like below

```
new_values = [OrderedDict([('Entry1', 'Van'), ('abc', 'Daro'), ('def', 'Mafa'), ('ghi', 'Jono'), ('jkl', 'Jono'), ('sum', 36)]), OrderedDict([('Entry2', 'Bus'), ('abc', 'Jono'), ('def', 'Mafa'), ('ghi', 'Joiu'), ('jkl', 'Joiu'), ('sum', 35)])]
```

If i want to access the value of `sum` in it, i am using the below code

`print(new_values[0]['sum'])`, Output: `36`

`print(new_values[1]['sum'])`, Output: `35`

is there a way to get back the index number if i give values of `sum`.

for a `List` i know that we have `.index` method, but since this is `List of OrderedDict` i am not sure how to approach this. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the index associated with each value, use a list comprehension:

```
pairs = [(d['sum'], i) for i, d in enumerate(new_values)]
```

Comment: how do i get the index value after this?